# Sum function in C++ with unknown number of arguments and types

Tags: c++, function, types, arguments

The first part of question is create a function (Sum) with unknown number of arguments, i've done it . It works very nice. But i have the struggle in second part , argument with different type like: int, float, double ... in one function call .  Any ideals i can fix my program ???

Thanks for your attention.

I think a lot people dont understand my question.
I want my program work also with different type od argument .
For example:
`sum(3, int x, int y, double z)` or `sum(4, double x, int y, float z, double t)`

> `cout << func(sum, 5, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0) << endl;` it work nicely with double , as i expected .

but

> `cout << func(sum, 5, 1.0, 2.0, 3, 4, 5) << endl;` it doesnt work

or even all numbers are integer, it's still not work as i expected , it return 0

> `cout << func(sum, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) << endl;`

```
double func(double (*f) (const double*, int) , int num, ...) {


  va_list arguments;

  /* Initializing arguments to store all values after num */
  va_start(arguments, num);
  /* Sum all the inputs; we still rely on the function caller to tell us how
  * many there are */

  auto *array = new double[num];

  for (int x = 0; x < num; x++) {
    double el = va_arg( arguments, double );
    array[x] = el;
  }
  va_end(arguments);                  // Cleans up the list

  return f(array, num);
}

double sum(const double *array, int n) {
  double result = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      result += array[i];
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: If your goal is to write C++ code, you will want to use templates, which incidentally will accomplish the same thing, instead of C-level hackery like `va_arg`. Do you know how to use templates in C++? If not, then where did you get this programming assignment from? This kind of a programming task is given only after introducing the basics of templates, in C++.

Comment: What was the topic of the teaching material from which this programming assignment was given? Typically, programming assignments are given after presenting a particular topic or subject matter in class, i.e., a programming assignment that involves virtual function is given after explaining how virtual functions work. Perhaps for this programming assignment you are expected to learn how to use `std::common_type`?

Comment: the topic is write function like sum, mean... with different number of argument by using `cstdarg` library and later change the function to work with different types like int, float, double also (not template ) like sum(int a, double b), sum(int a, float b, double c)...

Comment: No, that's not a programming topic. There is no C++ textbook with a chapter titled like that. A topic would be something like virtual functions, multiple inheritance, containers, algorithms, etc... What did you learn most recently, in class, from the instructor that you mentioned, that's related to this programming assignment? There is a particular template that, given one of those types, produces the so-called common type, i.e., int, float -> float. This is likely the intended solution. Perhaps you forgot it, if so you can consult your class notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you assume double as arguments, see this line:

```
double el = va_arg( arguments, double );
```

the usual solution is to provide format of the arguments passed to function, like in printf - but I suppose you don't want to do it.

I can suggest you use variadic templates like in this example:

```
template<typename T>
T func(T first) {
  return first;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
T func(T first, Args... args) {
  return first + func(args...);
}

int main() {
  std::cout << func(5, 1.0, 2.0, 3, 4, 5) << std::endl;
  std::cout << func(5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

You may change return type from T to double.

Comment: can you show me the ideal of function printf can do in this situation ?

Comment: `func` will return value like first argument i passed in ? I want more general , and the first argument will be the number of elements i will pass to function to calculate sum

Comment: C style printf takes a format string which specify type of each argument. So your solution would be: func(sum, "%d%f%f%d", 1, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4); So you would have to iterate the format to know what type each argument is - for %d you would use va_arg with int, for %f va_arg with float etc. Ugly and error prone.

Comment: You can change return type to `auto` - but I am not sure whether it is guaranteed to return common type of the arguments - maybe someone will post an answer? As to the number of elements, you don't need such sum function or the number of elements, the summation takes place in the func - where the + is.

Comment: I think its what im looking for , thanks you so much Marcin

Answer (score 2):

As a continuation of [marcinj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70319507/65863), a [variadic template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) is definitely the easiest way to go here. However, like you mentioned, you want to make sure the function be as generic as possible, so I would do it like this:

```cpp
template<typename ... Args>
auto sum(Args ... args) -> std::common_type_t<int, Args...>
{
    return (0 + ... + args);
}
```

Here `sum(Args ... args)` means it will take any amount of parameter, include 0 arguments.

Then you can set the return type with trailing return type. You might attempt to do it with:

```cpp
-> std::common_type_t<Args...>
```

However, this would give a compiler error if you passed 0 arguments to `sum()`, which is why I added `int` to it.

Then I used a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) to unpack the parameter pack, so `(0 + ... + args)` would be equivalent to:

```
((((0 + arg1) + arg2) + ...) + argN)
```

---

Note: the trailing return type is not necessary, you could as well just do:

```cpp
template<typename ... Args>
std::common_type_t<int, Args...> sum(Args ... args);
```

It just looks cleaner to me.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can use something called a template function, which allows for different types of variables. You can look at this here: [C++ Function Template](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/function-template)

Here is an example:

```cpp
template <typename T>
T add(T num1, T num2) {
   return (num1 + num2);
}
```

I would recommend passing an `std::vector<>` into the function and then using a for loop with `vector_name.size()` to iterate through each element and add them.

Comment: I know template , but i think it couldnt help .  I want to add different numbers of different types . Like double sum(5, int x1, double x2, int x3, float x4, double x5) or double sum(2, double x1, int x2)

Comment: @TheHo use a C++ style variadic template function, not a C style variadic function